# Recover wordpress by replace file manually

Tags: backup

lots of my websites got malware code in all files. But I actually have a backup of that site as a very old version. I can not update everything because there might have a lot of problems will happen.

1/ I install old site version on local, and manually copy folder wp-admin, wp-include, plugins, theme.. everything from old to new site except child-theme.
(this is a fastest way but I don't know there's any risk)?

2/ I backup old site completely and start working again (it will take a lot of time)

I can not freely try each way because although the site has problem, its displaying on server now and I am must not doing anything wrong or they are gonna kill me & they kill me hard.
So please advice me if the first way is ok to do?? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on where the malware is. If the code is on pages generated by WP 'core' because core files are damaged, then a reinstall of WP to 4.7.2 is the starting point.

Then I would reinstall all themes files, at least the active theme. You could manually install the active theme file in a new folder, then switch to that theme. But a reinstall of theme files (manually, via FTP) should overwrite damaged files.

I would also do the same thing with active plugsin: reinstall plugin files manually (via FTP) from 'fresh' files.

So if the core/theme/plugin files have been damaged, reinstalling manually will fix those files (and will give you the latest updates).

If you have not been keeping WP/themes/plugins updated to latest versions (um, bad dog), then there may be some theme/plugin database changes.

A full backup of everything is important to do - not just database, but core/theme/plugin files. You could download all of those to a local computer, then manually inspect the files for bad code. That might tell you where the infection is coming from.

Good luck.